# Bourbon Neat: I want to use omega(3n+1), but Neat disallows this. What's the alternative?

Tags: css, mixins, bourbon, neat

My first div spans 12 columns while the next divs only spans 3 columns. Something like this:

[image]

So I thought having omega(3n+1) to select the third div after the first one would be manageable. Turns out, as [it's said in Neat documentation](http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/#omega), composite argument such as 3n+1 is not supported.

I have tried `div:first-of-type ~ div { @include omega (3n); }` to select the third occurrence after the first div, but to no avail.

Any idea what's the alternative?

Comment: Do all the divs need to have identical markup - is it possible to have a different class on the first div?

Comment: @MikeHarrison it is possible, yes. But how would you style it? Because `nth-child` seems to count the first element too http://jsbin.com/cidebujiwo/edit?html,css,output And I can't change the first `div` to another element.

Comment: Hmm that's a gnarly one then - if possible I would work with a couple of containers, one for the top div and another for the bottom ones. I will see what I can do with your existing markup though